# Survey / List with different fields for each user

Tags: 2010, list, survey

I am supposed to create a survey that is used for an evaluation. The problem is that each user is going to be evaluated on different subject (which means the title should be different, entered by the site owner) and each suer can be evaluated in more then one subject.

I tryed this with surveys but it seems too much do create a new survey for each subject, I thought of using lists but then a user can see other usersanswers and this is not an option.

do you have any ideas? propositions? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but then a user can see other usersanswers

I'm not sure of that. You can **set authorizations on lists (this is sure)** *to avoid this (this is not sure)* no ? Then you'll be anle to put users in (several) groups, and give groups acces to lists.

This is just an idea as you ask :)

Regards,

Nico.

Comment: Thank you nico, but this is a very important part of the problem, users must not be able to see other users answers.

Comment: I cannot test it right now, sorry. But logically, if users have not permissions on a document library, they just cant even see it, I'm talking about the entire document library. So they won't be able to see documents in libraries. It's easy to test (if you have the infrastructure already installed). But about surveys i've never used it, so I can't help you on this; if it's just a document (like word) put in a document library, configure permissions and I'm almost sure it'll be all right.

Comment: I didn't think of that! thank you! It does work!

Comment: Permissions are given as i create each liste element and they can't see the rest of the lsit. Thanks again

Comment: @Maki13 :) If I can help someone, it's pretty cool. Have fun with sharepoint permissions now :p Nico

Answer (score 0):

A complex survey like this can probably not be done with a SharePoint survey out of the box.

If you have the Enterprise license with InfoPath Forms Services enabled, you can use InfoPath to deliver the survey and present each individual with the questions they need to answer.

InfoPath can handle data input and create forms based on parameters. It's not an easy task and it requires some work.

[Qdabra Software](http://www.qdabra.com/en/default.aspx) and their support site [www.infopathdev.com](http://www.infopathdev.com) have very good advice, sample files and videos on YouTube, especially with regards to surveys. You may want to take a look at that.

This probably does not answer your question, but the topic is so broad that a reference to a technology like InfoPath (and InfoPath on steroids with Qdabra's QRules) may put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you teylyn, I will look into Infopath but this still rises the problem of  one or more forms being created everytime we need a new form title